# The Conservative Vector Field

Tags: calculus

I was so confused about one vector field such that $F(x,y)=\left \langle \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \right \rangle $. I know the definition that a vector $F$ is called conservative vector field if and only if there exist differentiable function $f$ such that $\nabla f=F$. For the above vector field, I can find a scaler potential function $f=-\arctan(\frac{x}{y})$. So I can get $F$ is conservative. But I also know the theorem that if a vector field $F(x,y)=\langle P,Q\rangle $ on an open simply-connected region $D$ and $P_y=Q_x$, then $F$ is conservative. So I get the domain of $F(x,y)=\langle \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\rangle$ is $R$\ $0$ which is not an open simply-connected region. So I get $F(x,y)=\langle \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \rangle$ is not conservative. What is my misunderstanding?

Comment: See the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field#Irrotational_vector_fields) where it outlines pretty much the exact problem you have.

Answer (score 2):

The conditional statment that $\nabla f = F$ implies $F$ is a conservative field, only works when $F$ is over an [open and simply-connected](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ConservativeVectorField.aspx) region. Hence the statement does not apply and there is no paradox.

Comment: You mean I can not apply this two statements. I can understand it now. But is the given vector is conservative or not? Why?

Comment: @HHH not conservative. Your second argument is the correct one